# Third level of jQuery's menu not auto sizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu, width

I have the following issue:

[image]

As you can see the third level of the menu is very compressed. The second level is working perfectly. It's at the exact width of the content.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Daily & Yearly Reports</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Daily Settlement and Funding Overview</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">ESA Statement</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Settlement Summary</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Save ESA Cashbook</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">ESA Interest Summary</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    #menu {
        /*height: 48px;*/
        overflow: auto;
        width: 99.7%;
        font-size: 1em;
    }
    #menu > li {
        float: left;  
        width: auto;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    /*
     * Fix to make sure the menu appears above jTable
     */
    #menu > li > ul {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    #menu > li > ul > li > ul > li {
        float: left;  
        width: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Now check to my Updated answer Demo is this http://jsfiddle.net/THmub/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `whtie-space nowrap`

**As like this**

```
     #menu > li > ul > li > ul > li{
    white-space: nowrap;// add this line
float:left; // remove this line
    }
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THmub/3/)**

Comment: That worked but not 100%. You can see here that for some of the rows because they're so short two menu items have been combined on the 1 line: http://i.imgur.com/QckggH5.png

Comment: @mlevit Now remove #menu > li > ul > li > ul > li {flaot:left;}  ------ now remove float:left of your #menu > li > ul > li > ul > li -- Live demo as this http://jsfiddle.net/THmub/3/   I have updated my anser please check it